# IcCube returning null for currentmember.lag(1) when other dimension attribute is used in slicer

Tags: mdx, iccube

I'm trying to create a measure that holds the prior period value

Normally what you do is:

```
WITH Member Measures.PrevAmt AS ([Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(1),Measures.Amount)
SELECT {Measures.Amount,MEasures.PRevAmt} on 0
,{[Time].[Calendar].[year]
,[Time].[Calendar].[quarter]
,[Time].[Calendar].[Month]} on 1
from [sales]
```

works fine, but i only want to limit it to a particular year. Easy, add 
Where ([Time].[Year].[2008])

but the resultset returns null for prevamt where the .lagged member would be in 2007 (eg at the year level and and the 1st member of each subsequent level). SSAS MDX returns the expected result and there's nothing in the IcCube doco that says that .lag/parallelperiod etc functions execute after the slicer is applied and the final resultset is created...

I get the expected results if i hack something together like this

```
WITH Member Measures.PrevAmt AS ([Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(1),Measures.Amount)
SELECT {Measures.Amount,MEasures.PRevAmt} on 0
,{[Time].[Calendar].[2008]
,descendants([Time].[Calendar].[2008],1)
,descendants([Time].[Calendar].[2008],2)} on 1
from [sales]
```

but this breaks when we slice by an attribute that isn't in the select list (and this code is ugly and probably slower)

Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you add the MDX request that is creating the issue, you can't have the same hierarchy in axis and where clause (I'm a bit puzzled)

Comment: running the 1st query, we can see that for 2008 the measures are {Amount=586,350,PrevAmt=560,250}. But when you run "WITH Member Measures.PrevAmt AS ([Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Lag(1),Measures.Amount)
SELECT {Measures.Amount,MEasures.PRevAmt} on 0
,{[Time].[Calendar].[year]
,[Time].[Calendar].[quarter]
,[Time].[Calendar].[Month]} on 1
from [sales]
WHERE [Time].[Year].[2008]" PrevAmt is null for 2008

Comment: got it ........

Comment: Indulge me if I'm wrong this is how 'Attributes' are working in SSAS that is a concept that is not present in icCube

Comment: Yes, this is how attributes/single level hierarchies work in SSAS dimensions